# Permission denied while trying install vue/cli on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, vue.js, ubuntu, permissions

I'm trying to install **Vue CLI** on **ubuntu 20.04** with the following command:

```
sudo npm install -g @vue/cli
```

I got permission denied error

```
2021/06/13 14:35:24.163955 cmd_run.go:1002: WARNING: cannot create user data directory: cannot create "/nonexistent/snap/node/4749": mkdir /nonexistent: permission denied
```

I used the following code to solve the **permission denied** problem in the **directory** that I'm developing the project but the solution **did not solve** the problem

```
chmod -R 777 /Desktop/vuejs
```

Answer (score 0):

I founded the solution because I installed node js using **Snap package** from Snap Store, which has **different permission** caused the problem. installing **Vue CLI** using npm needed permission for making a directory in the snap directory, even **changing permissions** to 777 in the snap directory **is not a good solution** becouse changing file system directories permission like **snap** or **usr**  hurts your ubuntu operation system, in my case after changing **usr** and **snap** directory permission to 777 my root permission gone and I had to reinstall ubuntu operation system

> you can install node js **version 14.x** using apt with the following command

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | sudo -E bash -
```

> also the following link is useful to install other nodejs versions

[nodejs debinstall](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debinstall)